# Per week price in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have following table structure

```
id, startdate, hotelid, price
```

On front-end I am showing min and max price as `$35 - $671 (per day)` This is min and max price of the hotel per day. I can fetch the per day data based on `GROUP BY` hotelid and getting min/max price as below:

```
SELECT
    hotelid,
    MIN(price) AS `minprice`,
    MAX(price) AS `maxprice`
FROM
    hotel_price
WHERE
    startdate > NOW()
    AND
    price > 0
GROUP BY
    hotelid;
```

Now, customer wants to show per week price as min/max. But I am confused because I have data as per day basis in table, how should I calculate and show weekly SUM of price as min max? How we can do this in a mysql query?

Answer (score 1):

try in where

```
WHERE price > 0 and startdate BETWEEN NOW() and DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `WEEK()`, `YEAR()` functions as follows:

```
SELECT
    hotelid,
    week(startdate) AS `week`,
    year(startdate) AS `year`,
    min(price) AS `minprice`,
    max(price) AS `maxprice`
FROM
    hotel_price
WHERE
    startdate > now()
    AND
    price > 0
GROUP BY
    hotelid,  year(startdate), week(startdate);
```